# How to Bind Visibility of Several Controls on a Page

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, textblock

At the click of a button, I would like to be able to toggle the visibility of several items on a page simultaneously. What would be the best possible solution for this? For instance, I have about 15 TextBlocks that need to be either Visible or Collapsed based on when a button is pressed.

EDIT

In my view in each of my TextBlocks I am placing

```
Visibility="{Binding TextBlockVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}"
```

And my BoolVisibilityConverter class

```
public class BoolVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

so on a button click how can I get the Visibility of the TextBlocks to change? The following is not working

```
private void ChangeVisibility_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlockVisible = !TextBlockVisible;  //does not change Visibility of TextBlocks       
}

private bool textBlockVisible = true;

    public bool TextBlockVisible 
    {
        get
        {
            return textBlockVisible;
        }

        set
        {
            textBlockVisible = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TextBlockVisible");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

and in App.xaml

```
 <converters:BoolVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolVisibilityConverter"/>
```

Comment: how about : bind visibility property of all controls to single visibility/boolean property?

Comment: Ok I have a bool to visibility converter edit above, but I'm not sure how to change the visibility of my TextBlock's when a button is pressed. I actually need to change it from Visible to Collapsed, and back to Visible again as many times as the user requires.

Comment: on button click, set `IsEnabled = !IsEnabled;`

Comment: Alright I did, but nothing changed.

Comment: 2 possibilities I can think : 1. the property get changed bet view not updated (have you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`?). 2. Converter method doesn't get called, try to put breakpoint there to make sure `Convert` method fired when `IsEnabled` property changed

Comment: Ok I updated my solution a bit. I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. I set a breakpoint at `Convert` in my converter and nothing occurs.

Comment: how about the `Convert` method, does it get called when `TextBlockVisible` changed? This kind of approach working fine for me to hide/show multiple controls simultaneously.

Comment: No it doesn't. I'm not sure why. `TextBlockVisible` changes from true to false, but I don't see anything occurring at the Convert method.

Comment: Have you tried giving mode of binding like 'oneway. , 'twoway' and UpdateSourceTrigger in xaml?

Comment: What'll happen, if you set private bool textBlockVisible = false; If there is nothing happens, so (maybe stupid question) do you set DataContext for some element of your page (or page itself)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure a binding you have to specify the data source and the data property.

In your example code, you specify the source property 'TextBlockVisible'

```
Visibility='{ Binding TextBlockVisible ,
              Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}'

 <!-- No source set for binding -->
```

but you don't indicate the source itself.   When there is no source specified the binding framework looks at the **DataContext** property for the source.  Your TextBlocks don't have the DataContext set, so the binding framework examines the DataContext property on each parent element (until it reaches **phone:PhoneApplicationPage**  )

As @Oleg points out, you haven't set the DataContext, which is why the binding is not working.

Since the TextBlockVisible property is a member of your page class you need to set in the page constructor.

```
 public MainPage() {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;  
  }
```

FWIW, properties like TextBlockVisible are usually kept in a separate ViewModel class.  Then your setup code would be:

```
var vm = new ExampleViewModel();
DataContext = vm;
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will have to try this out, and I will also place the property in a ViewModel class.

Comment: With setting `DataContext = this` I can see the `Convert` method of `BoolVisibilityConverter` being called when the page loads, but not on the click event.

Comment: Not sure what to say.  I copied your code and added DataContext= this, and it worked.

Comment: my mistake, works great. I was missing something in the ViewModel. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you don't set **DataContext** of your page. **TextBlockVisible** is the property of the page class, so in the constructor of the page after the InitializeComponent you should have this

```
  public CurrentPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;  
  }
```

If there is no Source of Binding, it takes from DataContext.

Not the best, but also possible way to do what you want (to do it without INPC and binding from DataContext): you have to set the name of some element, that will change its visilility. In your click event you set

```
private void ChangeVisibility_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SomeElementName.Visibility = SomeElementName.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;       
}
```

And on the other elements you make binding this way:

```
Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=SomeElementName}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out as soon as I have a chance.